# how can i call each value in one function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when i calculate each price the problem is insert both.
I just want each price for pickup and delivery

Javascript

```
    function refreshprices() {

         var pickup_td = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(origin_lat,origin_lng,pickup_lat,pickup_lng);
         var pickup_cost = calculatePrice(base_cost, base_dist, additional_cost, additional_dist, pickup_td);

         var pickup_output = document.getElementById('pickup_price');
         pickup_output.innerHTML = " $ " + pickup_cost;

         var delivery_td=getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(origin_lat,origin_lng,delivery_lat,delivery_lng);
         var delivery_cost=calculatePrice(base_cost, base_dist, additional_cost, additional_dist, delivery_td);

         var delivery_output = document.getElementById('delivery_price');
         delivery_output.innerHTML = " $ " + delivery_cost;

}
```

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div id="pickup_option_calculate_price">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" >
        <h2>Pickup Option</h2>

        <label class="radio">
          <div class="option-title"><input type="radio" name="pickup" value="no_pickup" id="type_0" checked>No pickup required</div>
        </label>

        <div class="option-desc">You must drop off your passports and supporting documents at our office.</div>

        <label class="radio">
          <div class="option-title"><input type="radio" name="pickup" value="pickup" id="type_1">Pickup required ( <span id="pickup_price"> Enter Address to calculate Price </span>)</div>
        </label>

        <div class="option-desc">We will pickup the passports and supporting documents from your home or office.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pickup_location">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <input type="text" name="address" class="span10">
      <input type="button" name="search" class="span2" value="Calculate Price" class="btn">
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12">
              <div id="coords" style="margin-top: 10px;"></div>
              <div id="gmap" style="height:200px;position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="delivery_option_calculate_price">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" >
        <h2>delivery Option</h2>

        <label class="radio">
          <div class="option-title"><input type="radio" name="delivery" value="no_delivery" id="type_0" checked>No delivery required</div>
        </label>

        <div class="option-desc">You must drop off your passports and supporting documents at our office.</div>

        <label class="radio">
          <div class="option-title"><input type="radio" name="delivery" value="delivery" id="type_1">delivery required ( <span id="delivery_price"> Enter Address to calculate Price </span>)</div>
        </label>

        <div class="option-desc">We will delivery the passports and supporting documents from your home or office.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="delivery_location">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <input type="text" name="delivery_address" class="span10">
      <input type="button" name="delivery_search" class="span2" value="Calculate Price" class="btn">
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12">
              <div id="coords" style="margin-top: 10px;"></div>
              <div id="gmap" style="height:200px;position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

when i calculate each price the problem is insert both.
I just want each price for pickup and delivery
Image is below.

[image: pickup]

Comment: Please clarify: What exactly do you expect and how does the result differ from that?

Comment: Make sure you are passing the correct values to your functions. Since we can't run your code and don't know the values of the variables, that's something only you yourself can find out.

Comment: fistly I use only one map it working but i add next map and i change the pickup to delivery .

Comment: I want to know why the first calculation price are insert the second

Comment: Have you checked that both values, delivery_cost and pickup_cost are not the same ? The calculation of delivery_td sounds suspicious.

Comment: What makes you think `calculatePrice` does not produce the same result in both cases? **Debug** your code.

Comment: calculatePrize are correct bro.

Comment: The problem is when i call refreshprices() calculation value are insert both .

Answer (score 0):

Ok.Now i found it all my brother.

```
             refreshprices();
             pickup_output = document.getElementById('pickup_price');
             pickup_output.innerHTML = " $ " + pickup_cost;

             refreshprices();
            var delivery_output = document.getElementById('delivery_price');
            delivery_output.innerHTML = " $ " + delivery_cost;






function refreshprices() {

     var pickup_td = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(origin_lat,origin_lng,pickup_lat,pickup_lng);
     pickup_cost = calculatePrice(base_cost, base_dist, additional_cost, additional_dist, pickup_td);   

     var delivery_td=getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(origin_lat,origin_lng,delivery_lat,delivery_lng);
     delivery_cost=calculatePrice(base_cost, base_dist, additional_cost, additional_dist, delivery_td);

}
```

[image: work]